# Capturar campos formulário ExpandleListView

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `ExpandleListView` com cada item possuindo um layout próprio. Esse layout possui `Editexts`, `checkbox`, etc. Preciso capturar o que é digitado e selecionado em cada item do `expandle listview`. Alguém já utilizou essa abordagem?

```
 Adapter
public class AneurismaTratamentoAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<String> lstGrupos;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> lstItensGrupos;
    private Context context;
    private String aneurismaTratamentoEntity;
    private ArrayList<EditText> listaEditiText  = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    private ItemSuporte holder = null;
    public List<ItemSuporte> listaHolder = new ArrayList<>();

    public AneurismaTratamentoAdapter(Context context, List<String> grupos) {
        this.context = context;
        lstGrupos = grupos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return lstGrupos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return lstGrupos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return lstGrupos.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return lstGrupos.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_group_aneurisma, null);
        }
        else{
            convertView.getTag();
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.im_icon_list);

        if(groupPosition == 0 || groupPosition > 0){
            int iamgeResourceId = isExpanded ? R.mipmap.ic_seta_up_preto : R.mipmap.ic_seta_down_preto;
            image.setImageResource(iamgeResourceId) ;
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        else{
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        TextView tvGrupo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_item_menu_paciente);

        tvGrupo.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ItemSuporte holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_aneurisma,null);
            holder = new ItemSuporte();
            holder.aneurismaLargura = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_largura);
            holder.aneurismaComprimento = (EditText)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_comprimento);
            holder.containner = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ItemSuporte) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // Passar os parâmtros aqui caso tenha que preencher.
      return convertView;
    }

    public void clickButtonVerFotosAneurisma(final ItemSuporte holder){
        if(holder != null){
            holder.bt_ver_fotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    irTelaImagensAneurisma();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void clickButtonEnviarFotoAneurisma(final ItemSuporte holder){
        if(holder != null){
            holder.bt_enviar_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    irTelaEnviarFoto();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void irTelaImagensAneurisma(){
        Intent it = new Intent(context, ImagensAneurismaPacienteActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(it);
    }

    public void irTelaEnviarFoto(){

    }

    private class ItemSuporte {
        EditText aneurismaLargura;
        EditText aneurismaComprimento;
        Button bt_ver_fotos;
        Button bt_enviar_foto;
        View containner;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder tratar eventos de clique nos elementos que compoem layout dos items filho da lista, você pode adicionar os listeners de clique para cada elemento dentro do método **getChildView()** do seu adapter, pois este é o método que define o layout dos elementos filho:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item_filho, null);     

    EditText mEditText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);


    mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Seu código
        }
    });


    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Seu código
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Como eu posso armazenar os dados para que ao fechar um grupo, seu respectivo filho não perca os dados?